# Sending several files from server side using http 'POST' -send ArrayList of FileInputStream

Tags: java, json, arraylist, fileinputstream

I succesfully wrote an http 'post' that gets 1 file (image) from the server side like this:

```
@Path("getImage")
@POST @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM})
public Response getImage(picRequest request)  throws Exception {
     File file = ......
       return Response.ok(new FileInputStream(file)).build();
}
```

And I check it using client:

```
ClientResponse response = webResource
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .post(ClientResponse.class, inp);
```

The problem is that I cann't succeed when trying to send several files in a list. (ArrayList of FileInputStream)

```
ArrayList<InputStream> resultData = new  ArrayList<InputStream>();
while (rs.next()) {
    ....
    resultData.add(new FileInputStream(file));
}
  return Response.ok(resultData).build();
```

How do I do it? and what should be the MediaType?

Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: One request, one response. If you want to return multiple files in one request, consider zipping them up. EDIT: of course I completely miss that this is a RESTful webservice, you should tag that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider returning a multipart/mixed response. Here is an blog describing how to do this with Jersey specifically.

http://geekoolympics.blogspot.com/2013/02/jersey-mutipart-resource-that-produces.html